# Почему это CUDA-ядро дает результаты, отличные от результатов CPU-версии?

Tags: cuda, c++

Я портировал на CUDA этот кусок кода:

```
    if(_layersCount > 1)
    {
        for(int i=_layersCount-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i];j++) // cuda kernel
            {
                localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] = 0;

                for(int k=0;k<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1];k++)
                {
                    localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] += _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(i+1, k, j)]
                                                                    * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i+1, k)];
                }

                localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] *= derivatives[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)];
            }
        }
    }
```

Результат:

```
    if(_layersCount > 1)
    {
        for(int i=_layersCount-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            // calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers
            blocksCount = floor((double) _neuronsPerLayerCount[i] / threads.x) + 1;
            blocks = dim3(blocksCount, 1);

            calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers <<<blocks, threads>>> (deviceLocalGradients, _neuronsInputsWeights, deviceDerivatives, _neuronsPerLayerCount[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i+1], _neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1], _inputsInPreviousLayers[i], _inputsInCurrentLayer[i]);
        }
    }
```

Ядро calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers:

```
__global__ void calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers(double * localGradients, double * neuronsInputsWeights, double * derivatives, int neuronsCount, int neuronsInPreviousLayers, int neuronsInPreviousLayersWithCurrent, int neuronsInNextLayer, int inputsInPreviousLayers, int inputsInCurrentLayer)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if(idx < neuronsCount)
    {
        int neuron = neuronsInPreviousLayers + idx;

        localGradients[neuron] = 0;

        // this to Kernel, then reduce localGradients.
        for(int k=0;k<neuronsInNextLayer;k++)
        {
            localGradients[neuron] += neuronsInputsWeights[inputsInPreviousLayers + k*inputsInCurrentLayer + idx]
                                                            * localGradients[neuronsInPreviousLayersWithCurrent + k];
        }

        localGradients[neuron] *= derivatives[neuron];
    }
}
```

Но я вижу различия в результатах вычислений, начиная со второго знака после запятой. В чем может быть проблема? Все остальные ядра за исключением этого работают отлично.

Моя карта GF555M. Она поддерживает двойную точность.

Answer (score 2):

Я нашел в чем проблема. Оказалось, банальная опечатка. Вместо строки:

```
calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers <<<blocks, threads>>> (deviceLocalGradients, _neuronsInputsWeights, deviceDerivatives, _neuronsPerLayerCount[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i+1], _neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1], _inputsInPreviousLayers[i], _inputsInCurrentLayer[i]);
```

следовало написать:

```
calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers <<<blocks, threads>>> (deviceLocalGradients, _neuronsInputsWeights, deviceDerivatives, _neuronsPerLayerCount[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i+1], _neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1], _inputsInPreviousLayers[i+1], _inputsInCurrentLayer[i+1]);
```

Comment: Я все понял!

Answer (score 1):

Я пока не сильно вникал в код, но по совокупности Ваших тем, если расхождения действительно в сотых долях, то, возможно, "плавающие" параметры вычислений на CUDA часто мигрируют из одной памяти - в другую (CPU <-> GPU), ну, допустим - это весовые коэффициенты. Попробуйте держать их всегда на стороне GPU.

Либо, если так не получается, можно поэкспериментировать с параметрами округления:

1. либо только на GPU, если ими можно управлять,
2. либо на стороне CPU (в обоих исполнениях библиотеки), т.е. "подправлять" коэффициенты (сбрасывать погрешность) после итерации расчетов (которые мигрируют в GPU-версии).

Comment: В смысле мигрируют? Все данные, с которыми оперирует ядро, загружаются в память в самом начале и извлекаются только в самом конце. Единственное, что туда передается с хоста при запуске - это целочисленные константы. Мне тут на stackoverflow намекнули на race condition в этом ядре, но я его в упор не вижу

Comment: >Все данные, с которыми оперирует ядро, загружаются в память в самом начале и извлекаются только в самом конце.

Значит проблема может быть с округлением.

>Единственное, что туда передается с хоста при запуске - это целочисленные константы

А расчеты производятся в `double`. При загрузке-выгрузке `double<->int` могут появляться разногласия между `GPU` и `FPU`. Можно поэкспериментировать с точностью при округлении `FPU` (там всего 3 варианта) и добиться одинаковых результатов.